# SSAS Parameterized Named Query

Tags: sql-server, database, ssas, mdx, business-intelligence

Dears

I'm new to SSAS World, and am trying to enhance report performance by using Analysis services MDX Query

I know that SQL  differs from MDX, but I need hints if I can use parameters inside Named Query That I need to do  calculations for each record

Check this>> to calculate NO of Days Off

```
  OUTER APPLY ( SELECT    SUM([dbo].[DurationWithoutWeekend](CASE
                                                          WHEN @datefrom >= TCCDays.StartTime
                                                          THEN @datefrom
                                                          ELSE TCCDays.StartTime
                                                          END,
                                                          CASE
                                                          WHEN @dateto >= TCCDays.EndTime
                                                          THEN TCCDays.EndTime
                                                          ELSE @dateto
                                                          END)) AS DAYSOff
                  FROM      Tfs_DefaultCollection.dbo.tbl_TeamConfigurationCapacityDaysOffRange TCCDays
                  WHERE     IM.localId = TCCDays.TeamMemberId
                            AND ( TCCDays.EndTime >= @datefrom
                                  OR TCCDays.EndTime IS NULL
                                )
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: No. Yes. You're welcome.

Comment: Hahaha, thanks for  valuable info. :D

Comment: sql and mdx are different - very different - "alternatives" do and don't really exist - sometimes several lines in sql end up as 1 line in mdx and vice versa. Please add your mdx.

Comment: @SouravA I genuinely like your comment - how can we be specific when the question is so broad.

Comment: @whytheq - that was meant to be a joke :D This is indeed a very poor question.

Answer (score 0):

Check these out, try your luck..

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/10894_3743396_2/Support-Parameterization-from-Analysis-Services-150-Parameter-Defaults.htm

http://www.ssas-info.com/analysis-services-articles/50-mdx/1779-using-dimensions-as-parameters-to-calculations-and-sets